# Mad Catz R.A.T. 3 mouse problems on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mouse

I am having difficult time to customize the buttons on my RAT 3 mouse. I want my side buttons to go forward and backward. Anyone know how to do that?

Also scrolling wheel is inverted and I don't know how to change that?

Every time I reconnect my mouse, it doesn't register mouse settings according to always switching my DPI when I reconnect it. I am running on OSx El Capitan 10.11

Answer (score 3):

Download the R.A.T.E software from [madcatz](http://madcatz.com/downloads/) (under software), that allows you to wire up keys to forward and back, as well as setting the DPI properly.

Note, you have to allow the app in Security & Privacy after install completes [image]

The inverted scrolling wheel is due to OSX treating all mouse as a Magic mouse. Changing the scroll direction to natural in system setting will affect both the touchpad and mouse, which is annoying because the touchpad direction is right.
I recommend [Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/) which applies scroll direction separately.